# Django 2 + Channels динамическое обновления журнала событий

Tags: django, channels

Всем привет! Недавно начал изучать Django Channels прошу помочь правильно настроить передачу сообщения из view.

У меня простое приложение "Телефонная книга", пользователь вводит в форму поиска номер телефона и ему из базы данных выводятся данные о владельце номера.

В админке Джанго необходимо сделать что то типа журнала поиска, т.е. выводить данные о том каким пользователем был сделан запрос, какой текст был в запросе и время когда запрос был сделан.

С помощью Channels я хочу настроить динамическое обновление журнала событий. Чтобы не надо было каждый раз нажимать кнопку "обновить".

Код во views.py следующий

```py
class SearchView(ListView):
    model = PhoneBook
    template_name = 'search.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        # получаю данные запроса: автор, данные и время
        request_args = {
            'request_author': self.request.user.get_username(),
            'request_data': self.request.GET.get('search'),
            'request_time': datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(sep='T')
        }
        # записываю в базу данных
        request_history = RequestHistory(
            request_author=request_args['request_author'],
            request_data=request_args['request_data'],
            request_time=request_args['request_time']
        )
        request_history.save()
        # отправляю в consumer
        channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)("default", request_args)
        object_list = PhoneBook.objects.filter(phone_number=request_args['request_data'])
            if len(object_list) == 0:
                object_list = None
                return object_list
            return object_list
```

Код в consumers.py следующий

```py
class HistoryConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

    def receive(self, **kwargs):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.receive)('default')

    def send_to_history(self, event):
        request_author = event['request_author']
        request_data = event['request_data']
        request_time = event['request_time']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'request_author': request_author,
            'request_data': request_data,
            'request_time': request_time
        }))
```

В шаблоне странички следующий код

```html
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}


{% block extrastyle %}
{{ block.super }}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block extrahead %}
{{ block.super }}
<script>
    var historySocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/admin/mainapp/requesthistory/');

    historySocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var request_author = data['request_author'];
        var request_data = data['request_data'];
        var request_time = data['request_time'];
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'history';
        div.innerHTML = '<p>request_author</p>';
        document.body.append(div);
    };


</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div id="history">
    {% for object in object_list %}
    <div class="history">
        <p>{{ object.request_author }}</p>
        <p>{{ object.request_data }}</p>
        <p>{{ object.request_time }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

ASGI сервер работает. Подключение по вебсокет происходит.
В итоге динамического обновления не получается. Никакие сообщения об ошибках не выводятся. Помогите разобраться, что я не так делаю.

Comment: Проблему с обновлением решил полностью переписав код. За основу взял туториал из официальной документации. Сделал 2 вебсокет соединения, одно на странице поиска, другое на странице админа, где история прослеживается. Со страницы поиска через js передаю сообщение обработчикам, далее обновляю информацию тоже через js.